# OOP - how to call a function before the class constructor

Tags: c#, java, oop

I have a job interview tomorrow and I'm trying to answer this question:

There is a class named `C` and method `m` in this class, this class have also empty constructor:

```
Main ()
{
C c = new c();

}

Class C {

public c {

//empty constructor

}

public m {

//does something - doesnt mind

}

}
```

And what you have to do is to change the code so that in a creation of an instance class `C`, the method `m` would be called before the class constructor.

You have to do this without changing the `main` (edit only the class code).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: C# and Java are different languages...

Comment: What a stupid interview question.

Comment: A lot of times they want to see how you'll respond.  In this case, asking if m() could be made static might be appropriate.  Or perhaps not static but invoked in the constructor.  Of course, that isn't really 'before' the constructor, but whatev.

Comment: Obviously the only way to do this is by making a call to the function *m* inside the constructor. There's no other way to do it in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like the other answers have said, you can make the method static. But then you need to explicitly call it. If you make a static class constructor, that will get called once automatically (you don't need to call it), the first time the class is referenced (like when you construct the first instance). You can't exactly control when it executes, but it will execute before the first instance is constructed. Based on the way they've worded the question (you can't change the Main method), I think static class constructor is the answer they're looking for.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k9x6w0hc%28v=vs.80%29.aspx

> Static constructors have the following properties:
>       A static constructor does not take access modifiers or have parameters.
>       A static constructor is called automatically to initialize the class before the first instance is created or any static members are
>   referenced.
>       A static constructor cannot be called directly.
>       The user has no control on when the static constructor is executed in the program.

Java doesn't have static class constructors, but they do have static initialization blocks..

```
static {
    // code in here
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answers. the problem with making m a static method is:

I cant change the main so i cant call m() before the constructor, i can only

call m() within the constructor but m() wouldn't run exactly before the constructor..

(so what i still dont understand is how do i call m() before the constructor, even if m() is a static function - because i cant change the main())

Comment: @thechmodmaster If you make m a static class constructor, then it will execute automatically before you call the constructor to create a new instance.

Comment: I understand. So I need to change m() to static class constructor, not to static function.

Comment: Thanks a-lot to everyone!! you really helped me:)))

Comment: If you need to keep the method name "m", then make it a static function, and then create a static class constructor that calls it.

Answer (score 2):

To call a class's method before its constructor gets called you either have to turn this method into **static** so you don't need an instance of that class to call it, or (in C#) you can use [FormatterServices.GetUninitializedObject Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.formatterservices.getuninitializedobject.aspx) to get an instance of your class without running the constructor (which of course may not be a wise thing to do).

Comment: Nice trick but please consider maintenance problems in a team. This is not standard OOP practise, its very hard for an average programmer to understand. Lots of time would be wasted by team members looking for call to the constructor. Don't do it.

Comment: Yeah, you're right. But I'm not suggesting anyone to do it, and even MSDN states that *"The current method should only be used for deserialization when the user intends to immediately populate all fields*". I put it in my answer just for the sake of curiosity :).

Answer (score 2):

In both Java and C# you can use, base class constructors, static constructors (Edit: static initializer block in Java), and field initializers, to call code before the `C` class's constructor executes without modifying `Main`.

An example using a field initializer block in Java:

```
class C {

    { m(); }

    public C() {
        System.out.println("cons");
    }

    public void m() {
        System.out.println("m");
    }
}
```

This prints "m", then "cons". Note that `m` is called every time a `C` is constructed. A static initializer block would only be called once for the JVM.

Comment: @mikez I cannot compile this code. Are you sure that this works?

Comment: @mikez `Main.java:9: error: '}' expected` `int dummy = { m(); };` (and then some more error markers for missing `}`. But the code is correct when I remove the initializer block for `dummy`. BTW: Java 7, Ubuntu 12.04

Comment: .. and I don't see how this should work. why use an extra field if you just could add a block? and how would `dummy` be initialized?

Comment: @hage see my edit to the sample. the `dummy` field is unneccessary, but it still compiled on with java 6 on windows.

Answer (score 2):

**In JAVA:**
make method `static` and call your method in `static` block.

```
class C{

static{
    m();
}

public C() {
    System.out.println("Constructor Called..");
}

public static void m() {
    System.out.println("m() is called.");

}
}
```

Main call

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    new C();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Its basic OOP. You have to make a public static method and call it. That method can then call the constructor, or you can call the constructor directly from main.

Before you call the constructor, the object don't exist, therefore no instance methods exist, therefore nothing tied to the instance/object can be called. The only things that do exist before the constructor is called is the static methods.

Answer (score 1):

Following way seems to achieve what is required. Without using static methods/variables

```
namespace FnCallBeforeConstructor
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        MyClass s = new MyClass();

        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    partial class  MyClass: Master
    {
        public override void Func()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("I am a function");
        }

        public MyClass()
            : base()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("I am a constructor");
        }
    }

    class Master
    {
        public virtual void Func() { Console.WriteLine("Not called"); }

        public Master()
        {
            Func();
        }
    }
}
```

Output is:

I am a function

I am a constructor